# how to copy dvd with windows?

Tags: windows

I have Windows DVD and remote HP server
I need to install Windows via ILO.
I can not do this via internet because server internet connection is very slow. So I should create Windows DVD image and ask admins to burn it and to connect to server via external DVD-ROM. I've created *iso image of Windows DVD but now I can not write it on standard DVD because image is LARGER than a  DVD. How is that possible? Is it kind of protection?

Comment: I can't fully understand the question... Can you try to re-elabourate?

Comment: why windows dvd iso image can't be burned to blank dvd, nero claims that image is larger than a dvd

Comment: can you please be more clear about how you try to burn the iso to the DVD? as a file or as an image?

Comment: as an image. but Nero claims that image is too big. i'm using standard windows dvd and standard DVD-R. I've used NERO to create DVD image

Comment: Well, what is the file size of the ISO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard DVDs have a 4.7GB file size limit, dual layer disks have twice that (roughly).

If Nero is saying the image is too big for the disk, it's too big. You either need a bigger disk, or to split the files up onto two disks.

Answer (score 5):

There are four common different DVD sizes. If the source DVD has more capacity than the destination DVD, you won't be able to perform a one-to-one copy.

From [DVD Sizes - About.com, Digital Video Recording](http://dvr.about.com/od/dvdrecordableformats/f/faq5.htm):

> - DVD-5 holds `4.7 GB` and is supported by the DVD+R/RW and DVD-R/RW formats. It is also known as Single-Sided Single Layer.
> - DVD-10 holds `8.75 GB` and is supported by the DVD+R/RW and DVD-R/RW formats. It is also known as Double-Sided Single Layer.
> - DVD-9 holds `8.5 GB` and is supported by the DVD+R and DVD-R formats. It is also known as Single-Sided Double Layer (sometimes called Dual Layer). The official names are DVD-R DL and DVD+R DL
> - DVD-18 holds `15.9 GB` and is supported by the DVD+R format. It is also known as Double-Sided Double Layer (or Double-Sided Dual Layer).

(formatting mine)

Be aware that `GB` means gigabyte (1 billion bytes). Windows (wrongfully) uses `GB` for gibibytes (correct: `GiB`). As a result, a DVD-5 holds `4.37 GiB`.

Answer (score 2):

If it says it won't fit on the disk, then it won't fit on the disk. But you could try [installing windows using a USB drive](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=install+windows+using+usb+drive).